# Help to build a new email template and update an existing email template that is, will be attached to an Action

Tags: email, templates, actions

Is any anyone free to help with the work on the templates, we have one template we need to amend, make it a single column layout. Then build another template as a copy with blocks in a different order

Comment: Have you checked https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder yet?  It also has a link to the demo template creation https://vimeo.com/156633077

Comment: Since Julie mentions Actions I wonder if she means a Message Template, not a CiviMail Template. Julie, which is it? I don't think Mosaico helps with the first though will be happy to be told I am wrong

Comment: Hi Yes its a message template that we have built, from a civi action. Mosaico would not help with this, so correct.